# How can I remove xsi:type from SoapVar?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, xsitype

In PHP, `SoapVar` adds `xsi:type` with either content type or our manually chosen type.

```
$soapVar = new SoapVar('Foo', null);
// <TagName xsi:type="xsd:string">Foo</TagName>

$soapVar = new SoapVar('Foo', null, 'MyType');
// <TagName xsi:type="MyType">Foo</TagName>
```

Can I skip xsi:type entirely? I have a problem with missing `Struct` type in my 3rd party WSDL, so I'd like to skip `xsi:type`, as it's not needed. I don't want to set it manually to some mockup neither.

I tried to set it to emptyish value, but it behave just like skipped parameter, giving `xsi:type` automatically by value type. I know there is `XSD_ANYXML` const that makes me able to pass any raw XML, but it's not what I need.

Please advise.

Comment: `$soapVar = new SoapVar('Foo', XSD_STRING);` won't do the magic?

Comment: No, it will set it to `xsi:type="xsd:string"` and I have some tags inside those elements, so they are not strings.